# will new sql instance affect older sql instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, bids

We currently have `Sql Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition SP2` installed in our server. We have `BIDS`, and we use `SSRS` very much, which is used to host our reports.

I'll be installing `SQL Server 2012 Enterprise` as a new instance. So now we will have two sql server instances with (I assume) two versions of `Reporting Services`.

How would the URL change if I were to access the reports from `SSRS 2008`? Right now, I go to `http://OurServer/Reports`, `http://OurServer/ReportServer/`, etc to access `SSRS`.

How would this change when this new installation and this new sql server instance is created?

Thanks.

Comment: Those URL's are configurable via the SSRS Configuration Manger. The default naming scheme did not change from 2008 to 2012. You should be able to  access the manager and the reports as you do now once you have upgraded 2012.

Comment: The reason for installing it as a new instance was to make sure it didn't affect the old instance with 2008, specifically SSRS.

Comment: The issue is that I don't have the sql server 2008 installation CD, so if anything happens and Reporting Services stops working, then I don't have a way to go back. And that's the reason for the new instance of sql server 2012.

Comment: Sounds very risky. I've had a lot of trouble with the client tools (BIDS vs SSDT) breaking when they install side by side.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that will change with the new install of SQL Server and SSRS is the URL you use to access Report Manager and the Report Server (SOAP) service.

If your current URLs are as follows:

```
http://OurServer/Reports
http://OurServer/ReportServer
```

After you install a new instance of SQL Server and SSRS named SQL2012, then you will access the new install using the following URLs.

```
http://OurServer/Reports_SQL2012
http://OurServer/ReportServer_SQL2012
```

The existing URLs will not be effected by the new install. In other words, you will still be able to access the reports hosted on the older instance of SSRS using the original URLs.

Hope this helps.